# Specifying gradle file (not default build.gradle file) to build android studio standard project

Tags: android, gradle

For different purpose, I need to specify another gradle file (not default build.gradle file) to build android project in android studio standard structure.   When using eclipse with gradle, I know how to build project with specified name gradle file. Since the structure is a little different. How to make it work? Does anybody know it?  Thanks

Comment: Now officialy google do not support Android plu-in for Eclipse. Please check https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: I need to build project by gradle in AS project structure with gradle command in DOS.  For example, gradle assemblerelease -b a.gradle. But I don't know how to configure gradle setting in AS structure.

Answer (score 0):

More details to be explained.

I have an Android Studio standard project structure as below.

```
->Root
  -->app
     -->settings.gradle 
     -->build.gradle
  -->Project1 (library)
  -->Project2 (library)
  -->build.gradle
  -->settings.gradle
```

I want to create a new gradle file to build project to generate apk file. This gradle file has some tasks than the default one (build.gradle).

So I can choose one of them to use for different purpose.

For example, for A purpose, I can execute 'gradle assembledebug' to generate apk file.
for B purpose, I can execute 'gradle assembledebug -b b.gradle' to generate apk file.

I have done some research on this, but failed.